# Mongoose: Update multiple records with randomly generated data

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

There is a clients collection which is structured like this:

```
const ClientSchema = mongoose.Schema({
          name: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
          },
          region: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
          },
          balance: {
            type: Number,
            default: 0,
          },
          phone: {
            type: Number,
            unique: true,
            required: true,
          },
});
```

and here is the sample data I have stored:

```
[
  {_id: 'someID1', name: 'Joe Smith', region: 'USA', balance: 0, phone: 123456789},
  {_id: 'someID2', name: 'Kim Laws', region: 'CANADA', balance: 100, phone: 342345345},
  {_id: 'someID3', name: 'Dandy Cruz', region: 'EUROPE', balance: 2000, phone: 4536456456},
]
```

Data is displayed as a table on the client app, and users can modify the data on the table (something like a spreadsheet).

So suppose, after user messes around with the initial data, it mutated to something like this:

```
[
  {_id: 'someID1', name: 'Freedom Brights', region: 'AFRICA', balance: 2000, phone: 123456789},
  {_id: 'someID2', name: 'Kim Sun', region: 'ASIA', balance: 0, phone: 342345345},
  {_id: 'someID3', name: 'Dandy Cruz', region: 'EUROPE', balance: 2000, phone: 4536456456},
]
```

How would you update all these records on a single request with mongoose?

I've tried some googling and found methods like `update()` and `updateMany()` but all the examples out there doesn't exactly show how to approach this problem.

I would highly appreciate any help. Thank you!

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the bulkwrite

```
db.collection.bulkWrite( [
   { updateMany :
      {
         "filter" : <document>,
         "update" : <document or pipeline>,          // Changed in MongoDB 4.2
         "upsert" : <boolean>,
         "collation": <document>,                    // Available starting in 3.4
         "arrayFilters": [ <filterdocument1>, ... ], // Available starting in 3.6
         "hint": <document|string>                   // Available starting in 4.2.1
      }
   }
] )
```

also the document https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.bulkWrite